# How to setState from another class component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem.
I want after I successfully add product to cart my shopping cart badge will be updated. But I can't setState the itemCart component.
This is code when i add products in cart.
Function _datmon() will do that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,Dimensions,Image, TouchableOpacity,Modal, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { RecyclerListView, DataProvider, LayoutProvider } from "recyclerlistview";
import { Snackbar} from 'react-native-paper';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import Home from '../Home';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
export default class FoodByList extends Component{
   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            mang:[],
            dataProvider: new DataProvider ((r1,r2)=> r1!==r2),
            statusInform:false,
            modalVisible: false,
            id:'',
            gia:'',
            mota:'',
            soluong:1,
            mangmonan:[{
                id:'',
                soluong:'',
            }],
            getArr:[],
            hide: true,
        }
        this.home = new Home();
        this.homeref = React.createRef();
    }
   
    openModalWithItem(item) {
        this.setState({
            ten: item.ten,
            gia: item.gia,
            hinhanh: item.hinhanh,  
            id: item.id,
            mota: item.mota,
        })
    }
   
    layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider(
        index => {
            return index;
        }, 
        (type,dim) => {
        dim.width = Dimensions.get('window').width/2;
        dim.height = 280;
        }
    ) 
 
    _datmon = async()=>{
      
        //Get array availible device
        try {
            const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('keyOrdermonan');
            if (myArray !== null) {
              // We have data!!
              console.log(JSON.parse(myArray));
            }
          } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
            console.log(error);
        }
        const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('keyOrdermonan');
        if(myArray !=null){
            this.state.getArr = JSON.parse(myArray);
            //Id food currently 
            const check = {id:this.state.id};
            var position = 0;
            //Check id avalilabled in cart ? 
            const police = this.state.getArr.some(getA => getA.id===check.id );
            
            if(police==true){
                for(var i =0;i<this.state.getArr.length;i++){
                    if(this.state.getArr[i].id==this.state.id){
                        break;
                    }else{
                    position+=1;
                    }
                }
                this.state.getArr[position].soluong += this.state.soluong;
                this.setState({mangmonan: this.state.getArr});
                this.homeref.setSizeCart(this.state.mangmonan.length);
                console.log('Completely udrage quanity');
            }
            else if(police==false){
                this.setState({mangmonan: [{id: this.state.id, 
                                            soluong: this.state.soluong,
                                    }].concat(this.state.getArr)});
                this.homeref.setSizeCart(this.state.mangmonan.length);
                                    
            }
        }else{
            this.setState({mangmonan: [{id: this.state.id, 
                                        soluong: this.state.soluong,
                                    }]});
            this.homeref.setSizeCart(this.state.mangmonan.length);
           
        }
        
        // Add new cart
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('keyOrdermonan', JSON.stringify(this.state.mangmonan));
            // await AsyncStorage.removeItem('keyOrdermonan');
            this.setState({modalVisible:false,soluong:1});
            Alert.alert(
                "Thành công",
                "Đặt món thành công, vui lòng kiểm tra giỏ hàng",
                [
                   
                    {
                        text: "Kiểm tra giỏ hàng",
                        onPress: ()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('cart')}
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Tiếp tục đặt món",
                        style:'cancel'
                    },
                ]
                
            );
          } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
            console.log(error);
        }

     
    }
    getPriceVND = (giatri) => {
        const parts = giatri.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        const gia = parts.join(".");
        return gia;
    }

    rowrender = (type,item) => {
        
        return(
        <View style={styles.bgitem}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.wrapperitem} onPress={()=> {this.setState({modalVisible:true}),this.openModalWithItem(item)}}>
            <View style={styles.wrapperimg}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.hinhanh }} style={styles.img}/>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View style={styles.wrappername}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold' }}>Tên món ăn:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.under}>{item.ten}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.wrappername}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold' }}>Giá: </Text>
            <Text style={styles.under}>{this.getPriceVND(item.gia)}đ</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        
        )
        
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        //set lại tittle bar
        this.props.navigation.setOptions({title:this.props.route.params.tendanhmuc});

        fetch("http://192.168.43.25/DemoJWT/getMonAnByList.php",{
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept":"application/json",
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
                },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "IDDANHMUC" : this.props.route.params.id,
             })
        })
        .then((reponse)=>reponse.json())
        .then((reponseJson)=>{
            
           if(reponseJson==""){
               this.setState({statusInform:true});
           }else{
            this.setState({
                mang:reponseJson,
                dataProvider:this.state.dataProvider.cloneWithRows(reponseJson),
            })
           }
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })

    }
    render(){
        return(
            
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                {!this.state.hide &&  <Home ref={this.homeref} />}
               
                { !this.state.dataProvider.getSize()==0 &&
                <RecyclerListView
                    layoutProvider={this.layoutProvider}
                    rowRenderer={this.rowrender}
                    dataProvider = {this.state.dataProvider}
                />
                }

            {/* Thông báo khi không có món */}
            <Snackbar
                visible={this.state.statusInform}
                onDismiss={()=>{this}}
                action={{
                label: 'Trở về',
                onPress: () => {
                this.props.navigation.goBack()
              },
                }}>
               Hiện nhà hàng chưa có các món ăn này.
               Mong quý khách thông cảm !
            </Snackbar>
            {/* Thông báo khi không có món */}

            {/* Hiển thị khi nhấn chi tiết món ăn để đặt hàng */}
            <View>
                <Modal
                    animationType="slide" 
                    transparent={true}
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                 >
                <View style={styles.modalView}>
                
                <View style={styles.wrapperimgModal}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: this.state.hinhanh }} style={styles.imgModal}/>
                
                    <View style={styles.wrappername,{marginTop:15}}>
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18, }}>Tên món ăn:</Text>
                        <Text >{this.state.ten}</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={{ flexDirection:'column' }}>
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18, }}>Giá: </Text>
                        <Text>{this.getPriceVND(this.state.gia)} đ / 1 phần</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.wrappername}>
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18, }}>Mô tả:</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.mota}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.wrappername}>
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18, }}>Số lượng:</Text>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection:'row',marginLeft:0,marginTop:10 }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.decrease} onPress={()=>{
                                if(this.state.soluong==1){
                                    console.log('Không giảm nữa');
                                }else{
                                    this.setState({soluong:this.state.soluong-1})
                                }
                                }}>
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='minus-circle' color="black" size={24} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text>{this.state.soluong}</Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.increase} onPress={()=>{
                                if(this.state.soluong==15){
                                    console.log('Không tăng nữa');
                                }
                                else{
                                    this.setState({soluong:this.state.soluong+1})
                                }
                                }}>
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='plus-circle' color="black" size={24} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.totalbtn}>
                    <View style={styles.btn}>
                    <Button 
                        title="Hủy"
                        onPress={()=>{this.setState({modalVisible:false,soluong:1})}}
                    />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.btn2}>
                    <Button title="Đặt ngay"
                        onPress={()=>{this._datmon()}}
                    />
                    </View>
                </View>

                </View>
            </Modal>
            </View>
            {/* Hiển thị khi nhấn chi tiết món ăn để đặt hàng */}   


            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    wrapper:{
        flex:1,
        
    },
    wrapperitem:{
        flex:1,

    },
    title:{
        fontSize:30,
        padding:10,
        fontWeight:'bold',
    },
    bgitem:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'column',
        padding:10,
        margin:10, 
        borderWidth:1,
        borderRadius:15,
        backgroundColor:'#dddddd',

    },
    wrapperimg:{
        width:"100%",
        height:180,
        alignItems:'center',
        padding:5,
    },
    wrapperimgModal:{
        width:"100%",
        height:370,
        padding:5,
        marginLeft:10,
    },
    img:{
        width:'80%',
        height:100,
        borderRadius:10,
    },
    imgModal:{
        width:'100%',
        height:150,
        borderRadius:10,
    },
    wrappername:{
        flexDirection:'column',
    },
    under:{
        paddingLeft:10,
    },
    
    modalView: {
        margin: 20,
        marginTop:100,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 35,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 2
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        elevation: 5
      },
    totalbtn:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
    },
    btn:{
        width:90,
        marginRight:10,
      },
    btn2:{
        width:90,
        marginLeft:10,
    },
    decrease:{
        marginRight:10,
    },
    increase:{
        marginLeft:10
    }
})
```

Still here is your code setSizeCart() in class component Home.js :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {StyleSheet, Alert,View, StatusBar,Linking, Text} from "react-native"
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import HomeScreen from "./Screen/HomeScreen";
import FavouriteScreen from "./Screen/FavouriteScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./Screen/ProfileScreen";
import CartScreen from "./Screen/CartScreen";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { Appbar, Snackbar,Badge } from 'react-native-paper';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import {createDrawerNavigator} from "@react-navigation/drawer"
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SettingScreen from "./Screen/SettingScreen";
import BookingScreen from "./Screen/BookingScreen";
import FullFood from "./Screen/FullFood";
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


export default class Home extends Component{
    
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            token:"",
            ten:"",
            statusInform:false,
            searchQuery:"",
            getMangAsync:[],
            itemcart: 0 ,   
        }
        this.setSizeCart = this.setSizeCart.bind(this);
    }
    setSizeCart (bien){
        try {
            this.setState({ itemcart: bien });
            console.log("set thành công");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }   
    }
    _getasyc = async()=>{
        try {
            const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem("keyOrdermonan");
            if(key!==null){
                this.setState({getMangAsync:JSON.parse(key)});
                this.setState({itemcart:this.state.getMangAsync.length});
            }
         } catch (error) {
             console.log(error)
        }    
    }
    checkInternet(){
        NetInfo.fetch("http://192.168.43.25/DemoJWT/checkToken.php")
        .then(state=>{
            console.log(state.isConnected)
            if(state.isConnected==false){
                this.setState({statusInform:true})
            }
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this._isMounted = true;
        if(this._isMounted){
            this.checkInternet();
            this._getasyc();
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this._getasyc();
        // console.log("đã"+ this._isMounted)
    }   
    

    _logout = async() =>{
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem("keyToken");
            Alert.alert("Đăng xuất");
            this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    contact(){
        Alert.alert(
            "Liên hệ với chúng tôi",
            "Bạn có muốn hay không?",
            [
                {
                    text: "Hủy",
                    style:'cancel'
                },
                {
                    text: "Đồng ý",
                    onPress: ()=>Linking.openURL('tel:$+84705982473')
                }
            ]

        )
    }
    
render(){
    //    const {ten} = this.props.route.params
        return(
            <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor='#555555' barStyle="light-content" />
                <Appbar style={styles.appbar}>
                    <Appbar.Action icon="format-list-bulleted" onPress={()=>(this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer()))}/>
                    <Appbar.Content title="GREAT FOOD" />
                    <Badge  
                        visible={this.state.itemcart && this.state.itemcart >0}
                        size={17}
                        style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 5, right: 55 }}>{this.state.itemcart}</Badge>
                    <Appbar.Action icon="cart" onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('cart')}}/>
                    <Appbar.Action icon="phone-in-talk" onPress={()=>{this.contact()}}/>
                </Appbar>
                
                <Drawer.Navigator 
                    overlayColor="transparent"   
                > 
                    <Drawer.Screen name ="home" component={HomeScreen} 
                        options={{
                            drawerLabel:"Menu",
                            drawerIcon:({color})=>(
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
                        ), }}
                        />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="profile" component={ProfileScreen}
                            options={{
                            drawerLabel:"Hồ sơ",
                            drawerIcon:({color})=>(
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-circle" color={color} size={26} />
                        ), }}
                    />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="fullfood" component={FullFood}
                        options={{
                            drawerLabel:"Tất cả món ăn",
                            drawerIcon:({color})=>(
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="food" color={color} size={26} />
                        ), }}
                    />
                    <Drawer.Screen name= "favourite" component={FavouriteScreen}
                        options={{    
                            drawerLabel:"Yêu thích",
                            drawerIcon:({color})=>(
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="heart-pulse" color={color} size={26} />
                        ), }}
                    />
                     <Drawer.Screen name= "booking" component={BookingScreen}
                        options={{
                            drawerLabel:"Đặt bàn",
                            drawerIcon:({color})=>(
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="table-furniture" color={color} size={26} />
                        ), }}
                    />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="cart" component={CartScreen}
                        options={{
                            drawerLabel:"Giỏ hàng",
                            drawerIcon:({color})=>(
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cart" color={color} size={26} />
                        ), }}
                    />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="setting" component={SettingScreen}
                        options={{
                            drawerLabel:"Cài đặt",
                            drawerIcon:({color})=>(
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="wrench-outline" color={color} size={26} />
                        ), }}
                    />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
             <Snackbar
                visible={this.state.statusInform}
                onDismiss={()=>{this}}
                action={{
                label: 'Tắt',
                onPress: () => {
                this.setState({statusInform:false})
              },
             }}>
            Vui lòng kiểm tra kết nối.
            </Snackbar>
        </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:'center',
    },
    logout:{
        marginTop:50,
    },
    appbar:{
        backgroundColor:'#555555' 
    },

})
```

And I have been received warning is:

Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to this.state directly or define a state = {}; class property with the desired state in the Home component.

Can anyone help me!

Comment: post the full code

Comment: What full code class do you need ? So I think code is long

Comment: The file that contains the `_datmon` function should be enough. But if possible create a expo snack using https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: I updated code the file contains _datmon

Answer (score 0):

So one small thing you are missing here is that,

Creating a new component using the `new` keyword is not going to mount that component into the render tree.

You should include it inside the `render` function of your `FoodByList` like this

`<Home ref={this.homeRef} />`

Then, in the `constructor` of your `FoodByList` component, create the `homeRef` using

`this.homeRef = React.createRef();`

More on `React.createRef` in this [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Basically assigning a ref to the `Home` component inside the `render` of `FoodByList` gives you the ability to call the functions inside the `Home` component.

Next, in `Home` component's constructor use `this.setSizeCart = this. setSizeCart.bind(this)` or else convert the `setSizeCart` function into an arrow function like this

```
setSizeCart = (bien) => {
    try {
        this.setState({ itemcart: bien });
        console.log("set successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

So now, instead of doing
`this.home.setSizeCart(this.state.mangmonan.length)`
you should be doing
`this.homeRef.current.setSizeCart(this.state.mangmonan.length)`

Comment: I tried . And i received warning : Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _this.homeref.setSizeCart is not a function. (In '_this.homeref.setSizeCart(_this.state.mangmonan.length)', '_this.homeref.setSizeCart' is undefined)

Comment: updated the answer. This is happening because you have not bound the `setSizeCart` to the `Home` class.

Comment: It still returns the same warning as above

Comment: Update your question to include the new code inside the `FoodByList` component and also paste complete code of your `Home` component. Also can you use https://snack.expo.io/ to create a sample ?

Comment: In your code, you have `{!this.state.hide &&  <Home ref={this.homeref} />}`. But the `hide` value is always `true`, so the `Home` component never gets rendered. 
Also my mistake, you have to use `this.homeref.current.setSizeCart` instead of `this.homeref.setSizeCart`, updated the answer.

Comment: So, first the `Home` component should get rendered in order to use `this.homeref.current.setSizeCart` function

Comment: Yeah. It is working. But componen all of the Home  show at screen foodbylist. I don't want that

Comment: you can use conditional rendering inside `Home` component saying `if (this.state.itemcart == 0) return null;`  and once you set the state from the other component, it will become visible. Does this work ?

Comment: It not work. I still receive result the same

Comment: I think I can base your instructions, I can complete my task.I will try  snack.expo.io , Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Cool, do tell me if it works. We can update the answer so that it can help others looking for the same problem. Or you can suggest modifications to get the current answer accepted.

Comment: Hey bro. I solved my proplem is use listeners focus to me update the components and your tutorial by creatRef() to call them. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Tell me if anything needs to be updated in the answer. If there is nothing, consider selecting it as the correct answer to make it easier for others to see.